# Rotating objects in 3D like oprah's ipad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

m curious to knw how to get the funky 3D rotation 360 rotation of items, in the same way like that in oprah's ipad app. here the youtube link
[Oprah's Ipad App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M6mMmAhbh8)

Any one has got any ideas?? Is it opengl stuff???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just looks like a series of still frames shot from different angles.

To achieve this effect, take a bunch of photos that circumnavigate the object in question, and cycle through them in response to swipe gestures. Just think of it as taking a short film of some action (circling the shoes, opening the book), and then play the frames forwards and backwards in response to swipes, rather than just one after the other in a linear movie progression.

Comment: Yes, I believe Elements uses a similar technique.

Comment: @user462533 - Take a series of incremental photos of an object at various angles and swap them in and out in response to movement of a finger across the display.  The hard part will be the photos, as the rest is easy to code.

Comment: can you get me the link where i can find such pics...so that i can try??

Comment: @user462533: Coming up with content is your problem and most definitely off-topic.

Comment: so is it like i've to apply FIFO in the NSARRAY??

Comment: FIFO? That could only conceivably apply with a linear progression of frames (i.e., a movie). And even then it isn't necessary. Just store them in an array and use an index that goes up as they swipe to the right — wrapping when it reaches `arr.count` — and down when they swipe to the left, wrapping when it passes 0. The best technique is to remember the current index and the touch position in `touchesBegan` and then, in `touchesMoved`: `index = remembered_index + k*(touchpos.x - remembered_touchpos.x)`, where *k* is a "gearing" factor.

Comment: You can also avoid wrapping-logic by adding some large number to the index in `touchesBegan` — `remembered_index = 1000*arr.count`. You then compute the swipe index in `touchesMoved` thus: `index = (remembered_index...)%arr.count`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of photography is call 360 product photography